# Fails to change the language of a WP site

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm building a WP site for a Spanish company, and I want to change the language of the site (not the admin area's language). 
All the posts and the things that I put in the site are in Spanish, since I created them, but the default texts of the theme are in English (for instance, the string "search" inside the search box).

When I'm trying to change the language through **Settings -> General -> Site language** to *"Español"*, it changes. But after I refresh the page it returns to "en_US" again, and in the bottom it says:

> Note: The WPLANG constant in your wp-config.php file is no longer needed.

I did change the `WPLANG` in `wp-confing.php` to `define('WPLANG','es_ES')`, doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you have put the language files in the right place.
So, first you need to download spanish language files, [you can find here](http://i18n.svn.wordpress.org/es_ES/trunk/messages/)

and then put them into /wp-content/langauges folder, if no, create it.

[you can find full tutorial here](http://www.wikihow.com/Change-the-Default-Language-in-Wordpress)

Comment: I checked that folder (/wp-content/langauges) and it has two filles call "es_ES.po" and "es_ES.mo", which mean I have the language in the right place right?

Comment: Yes, @Avishay its ok. Activate the language, adding `define('WPLANG','es_ES')` to your `wp_config.php` file.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to download [spanish version](http://es.wordpress.org/).

All files of wordpress system will translate to Spanish, BUT, some words of your current theme installed maybe are in english, you'll translate it.

In `search.php` you will find the input box, where you will change the word "**Search..**" this are in **Apparence (Apariencia)** -> **Editor (Editor)**

Comment: OK, I'm there, in the "value" attribute there is a function get_search_query, not string to change. and how do I change the "read more" in the posts section? It stays in english too... Thanks!

Comment: What theme are using? Its depend of programing of this. Some themes have an option panel, to change this, but..if u provide the name, maybe i can help you. You've to change all string of `index.php`, `single.php`, `searchresult.php` and `category.php`, sometimes thats strings are in `archive.php`, but its depend of theme!

Comment: I searched every file you specified, no strings there, just a lot of "gets" functions. The theme was created by a programmer who is no longer work in the company :/ I know I don't have enough details. I  will try and keep searching for that strings.

Answer (score -1):

First, make sure the theme you are using is multi-language.

If no:

You need to translate the theme files located in `wp-content/themes/`

-EDIT:

You need to download the correct theme to your computer and manually edit the files within the theme folder, then upload it again.

Basically just go trough the theme code and replace the english text you see, for example "next post"/"previous post" to the correct sentence in Spanish in your case.
Just make sure to not edit anything you don't understand :)

Give me a shout if you need more help :)

Comment: @Avishay Edited the answer above, if you need more help let me know :)

Comment: I need to translate every word? there is a folder inside the theme folder called "languages" and it contains file call "es_ES. po" and "es_ES.mo", shouldn't it translate my site automatically? there is no  method to define specific file inside that folder to be my theme language? I didn't create that theme so I don't know where to find all the strings, it's actually a child theme.

Comment: @Avishay Basicly the people who design the themes decide which languages it's in. If they decide not to make a Spanish version you will need to add a translation yourself.